# Globally increase #maxlength attribute of textfield (form api)

Tags: 7, theming, forms

I have thousabds of field for admin to edit data which is saved in db from mobile app. i can fetch those data into text field while editing but drupal having default #maxlength of 128 character but in my case i have data field which is more than 128 character so its creating problem while saving those data in db. Pls help..
i tried to hack drupal core by writing code in from.inc.

```
function theme_textfield($variables) {
   $element = $variables['element'];
   $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'text';
+  // Remove maxlength when it's too long to be useful. 
+  if ($element['#maxlength'] >= 128) {
+    unset($element['#maxlength']);
+  }
   element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'value', 'size', 'maxlength', 'placeholder'));
   _form_set_class($element, array('form-text'));
```

but it dint work. pls tell me any solution.

Comment: Which form are you using? Any custom form of drupal build in form ??

Comment: i created form using hook_form. Can you please tell me how do i change default #maxlength of textfiled. If you have any idea of removing this attribute that will also work for me. @rupesh